# java ByteBuffer writing into file charset issue

Tags: java, character-encoding, nio

There's a method that encodes a file

```
public static void cipher(File input, int[] key, File output) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(input);
    FileChannel fcin = fin.getChannel();

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream( output );
    FileChannel fcout = fout.getChannel();

    ByteBuffer temp;

    while (true){
        buffer.clear();
        int r = fcin.read(buffer);
        if(r == -1){
            break;
        }
        //cb = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(cipherBuffer(buffer,key));
        //System.out.println(cb.toString());

        temp = cipherBuffer(buffer,key);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.print((char)temp.get(i));
        }


        temp.flip();
        fcout.write(temp);

    }


}
```

The `cipherBuffer()` method changes the initial Buffer according to a given key.
Tried to use commented code, but it didn't help. For now it even doesn't write to the `output`

```
public static ByteBuffer cipherBuffer(ByteBuffer initialBuffer, int[] key){
    ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        result.put(i, initialBuffer.get(key[i]));
        //System.out.println(result.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

That's how the output looks like at this stage

```
￐ﾰ￐￐ﾺﾷﾻ￐￐ﾰﾲﾀ￑ ￐ ﾾ￐￐ﾳ￐￐ﾑ￐ﾾﾴ￐￐ ﾵﾃ￐ﾾﾻ￑￐￐
```

Comment: Tested it with cipherBuffer() implementation simply returning the input. Works as expected. The issue maybe in your cipherBuffer() method.

Comment: cipherBuffer method is pretty primitive, don't think it's working wrong

Comment: What you think is *irrelevant.* If what you think was correct, your code would work; you wouldn't have a problem; and you wouldn't be posting here.

Comment: What input file do you use and what is the expected output?

Comment: I expect to see the same text, but every 10 symbols would be mixed according to the given key